# How to quickly switch between layouts in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, user-interface

I use different window-setups for Visual Studio depending on whether I'm at work, and have three monitors available, or e.g. at home, where I typically only have my laptop.

I've found a setup I like for each situation, and saved these using the export wizard, as shown below; for those who might not be aware, this can be done with the opton **Tools -> Import and Export Settings**.

I like the ability to do this, but I'd like it even more if I could do it without having to click a whoping 9 (!!) times to switch from one mode to the other. Ideally, I'd like to be able to "quick-switch" between home- and office-mode with just one or two clicks, but any improvement would help.

I know this might sound like an insignificant issue (which I suppose is true), but it's been bugging me for a while, and the only "improvement" I've been able to come up with so far is to add a button to the toolbar, as shown below. All this does though, is let me start the wizard without opening the **Tools** menu.

I can't possibly be the only one using this, so I'd like to know if there are any better ideas or solutions out there?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio 2015 and 2017 support Loading and Saving different Window Layouts without using the Import/Export settings feature.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4k7zyeba.aspx

> #### Switch between the layouts
>
> To switch between layouts, use the Keyboard shortcuts, or from the main menu choose Window > Apply Window Layout.

You can also create toolbar buttons that switch directly to a layout:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I didn't know about this.